# Android soundboard onpause

Tags: android, button, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with my soundboard im quite new to programming and i need help from some pros

The Problem is that my soundboard doesnt stop when i press the home button or the return button i need it to pause the sound or stop it here is the code hope you can help

```
package com.example.firstly;

import java.io.IOException; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Mymenu extends Activity {    
        int selectedSoundId; 

        @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); 
            final Resources res = getResources(); 

            //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou 
            final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.dinal, R.id.ele, R.id.syl, 
                                      R.id.amel, R.id.krz, R.id.mar, 
                                      R.id.sra, R.id.bab, R.id.har, 
                                      R.id.kur,  }; 
            final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.dinal_ama, R.raw.daj_ama, R.raw.syl_ama, 
                                      R.raw.ame_ama, R.raw.krzy_ama, R.raw.marihuanen_ama, 
                                      R.raw.srac_ama, R.raw.zajeb_ama, R.raw.hardcore_ama, 
                                      R.raw.oookurwa_ama,  }; 

            View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset 
                    //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding 
                    //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing. 
                    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) { 
                        if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) { 
                            selectedSoundId = soundIds[i]; 
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]); 
                            player.reset(); 
                            try { 
                                player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { 
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            } 
                            try { 
                                player.prepare(); 
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) { 
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            } 
                            player.start(); 
                            break; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }; 


            //set the same listener for every button ID, no need 
            //to keep a reference to every button 
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) { 
                Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]); 
                registerForContextMenu(soundButton); 
                soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener); }
            } 


        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();


        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop or pause the player in your activity's on pause, use the code below

```
package com.example.firstly;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Mymenu extends Activity {
    int selectedSoundId;
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        final Resources res = getResources();

        // just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
        final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.dinal, R.id.ele, R.id.syl, R.id.amel,
                R.id.krz, R.id.mar, R.id.sra, R.id.bab, R.id.har, R.id.kur, };
        final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.dinal_ama, R.raw.daj_ama, R.raw.syl_ama,
                R.raw.ame_ama, R.raw.krzy_ama, R.raw.marihuanen_ama,
                R.raw.srac_ama, R.raw.zajeb_ama, R.raw.hardcore_ama,
                R.raw.oookurwa_ama, };

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
                // the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the
                // corresponding
                // sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
                for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                    if (v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                        selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res
                                .openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                        player.reset();
                        try {
                            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            player.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        player.start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // set the same listener for every button ID, no need
        // to keep a reference to every button
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
            Button soundButton = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
            registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
            soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        player.stop(); // to stop the player
        player.release(); // if you want to pause the song use player.pause();

    }

}
```

Comment: i get 2 errors on the player when i use this code what can i do to not get them ?

Comment: final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); (line :23) cut this line of code and paste it below int selectedSoundId;  (line : 16)